# How can I have motion on a tile map?

Tags: python, html, python-imaging-library, mapnik

I'm interested in doing something like this:

http://hint.fm/wind/gallery/oct-30.js.html

It seems like a tile map, are the tiles animated gifs?  If not how can this animation be achieved?

I was thinkimg to use PIL to generate the gifs and serve it up with mapnik/tilestache, but tilestache doesnt seem to support .gif tiles.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using Javascript, I'd recommend using the excellent d3 library available here: http://d3js.org/
In particular, it has great support for maps. Check out this example and tell me whether it's similar to what you want to achieve: http://bl.ocks.org/karmi/raw/2366285/

Comment: pretty, but Im looking for something to animate the tiles, the example you gave is static.

Comment: No, it's dynamic. Click the autoplay link on the bottom of the page.

Comment: ok, i see.  Hmmmm, looks like its just flipping color values of polygon objects.  I'm trying to figure out something to show directional motion.

Comment: This could probably be achieved through transitions. Check the link here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/